# QEMU: No graphics after trying to start from terminal

Tags: graphics, display, qemu

I tried to turn on the virtual machine from the console for the first time, as the guide I was following suggested using `sudo virsh start webdev`, whereas I have always just used the QEMU interface.

However, ssh didn't work and nothing showed up in the QEMU graphical console, so I shut it down with `sudo virsh shutdown webdev` and tried to power it up in QEMU's user interface.  Now it's just a black screen, no matter how long I wait for a desktop.

Everything was working fine until I tried to extend the hard drive.

I followed steps 1,2 and 3 on this guide https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-extend-increase-kvm-virtual-machine-disk-size/, which resulted in the following commands being issued:

[Virtual Machine Powered Down]

On Host:
`sudo qemu-img info /var/lib/libvirt/images/webdev.qcow2`

[Confirmed no snapshots exist]

`sudo qemu-img resize /var/lib/libvirt/images/webdev.qcow2 +8G`

I was told "image resized" without any errors, although when I ran:
`sudo fdisk -l /var/lib/libvirt/images/webdev.qcow2`

...the disk didn't appear to be that much larger.

I then tried to power up the vm using `virsh start webdev` as I mentioned, but couldn't ssh, so I used `virsh shutdown webdev` and tried to get in through the QEMU UI - however, it's still not working.  When I try to start it through the QEMU interface, I keep getting a flash of gray text and then just a black screen, not even a Ubuntu logo.

Oddly enough, I do see the "Kubuntu" logo flash quickly in the QEMU display console when I issue a shutdown command to the guest.  And it still captures keyboard and mouse input; but I never get a desktop.

Any help greatly appreciated.